# How to run .reg file in Java

Tags: java, registry, runtime

I need to install a .reg file (INTRANET) by using Java. How do i get my goal ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [System.exec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) to launch `regedit yourfile.reg`

Here is how to do it :

```
String[] cmd = {"regedit", "yourfile.reg"};
Process p = Runtime.exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
```

Last line is optional, it only allows you to wait until the operation is over.

Answer (score 6):

If you're already on Java 1.6, just grab [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:/yourfile.reg"));
```

It will launch the file using the default application associated with it, as if you're doubleclicking the particular file in Windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

This can achieved through Process Builder in JAVA. Please consider the following  example for this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("regedit", "reg_file_to_run.reg");
Process processToExecute = processBuilder.start();
```

And then you can optionally wait for the completion of process execution with this line:

```
processToExecute.waitFor();
```

**Note:** If command in your registry file asks for confirmation prompts while making changes in registry entries, you can perform it silently as well with *'/s'* option. Like this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("regedit", "/s", "reg_file_to_run.reg");
```

With this command would be executed silently without any confirmation prompt.